# Micro-USB to HDMI

Tags: usb, hdmi, mhl

I've bought [this adapter](http://pages.ebay.com/link/http://pages.ebay.com/link/?nav=item.view&id=361148599009), but I couldn't make it work. I've read about MHL, but I don't really know if my phone supports it: I have a THL 5000 (also I have a Sony Xperia M dual), and a Hyundai DLF40285 40" Smart TV.

Can someone help me to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Check this site: http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/thl-5000-octacore-mtk6592t-root-recovery-t2835857/page21
`THL 5000 phone supports HDMI?`

I don't think so ;)

Comment: http://www.android-hilfe.de/thl-5000-forum/624999-thl-5000-bildschirmuebertragung-2.html
A german user posted: `Das THL5000 unterstützt kein MHL.` It simply means no. - Please rate my answer ;)